# Как сделать что бы при прокрутке сайта, определённые кнопки оставались на экране, в указанном месте

Tags: css

Есть вопрос, не получается его реализовать, помогите пожалуйста с решением:

---

Если статья большая и не умещается на экране то при прокрутке статьи иконки с возможностью голосования остаются неподвижными относительно экрана:
[image: http://i.pixs.ru/storage/7/2/1/2png_6797391_5269721.png]

---

Останавливается относительно статьи и уходит за рамки экрана только перед окончанием статьи:

[image: http://i.pixs.ru/storage/7/1/6/1png_8516200_5269716.png]

---

А также:
Если статья большая и не умещается на экране, то после нажатия «Развернуть» снизу экрана справа от статьи появляется плавающая ссылка «Свернуть»:

[image: http://i.pixs.ru/storage/7/2/3/3png_6424300_5269723.png]

---

и при прокрутке статьи остаётся неподвижной относительно экрана:

[image: http://i.pixs.ru/storage/7/2/8/4png_1765262_5269728.png]

---

как только появляется завершение статьи и/или всех комментариев и начинается новая статья, ссылка «останавливается»(движется относительно экрана на против конца статьи/комментариев):

[image: http://i.pixs.ru/storage/7/3/0/5png_1217196_5269730.png]

Comment: @vitagame, Вы хотите чтоб вам тут задаром такой функционал организовали?! Это не [freelance.ru](http://freelance.ru/ "Удалённая работа, фриланс"), а [HashCode.ru](http://hashcode.ru/ "Хэшкод - сеть знаний"), тут людям помогают а не делают работу за них!

Comment: Самый умный?

Готов заплатить.

Comment: На чистом CSS вы этого не сделаете. Смотрите в сторону jQuery. И разделите вопрос на части, показав что уже сделано.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, то надо что бы при прокрутке экрана кнопка оставалась на своем месте. То для этого есть свойство которое определяет положение от экрана, а не от блока.

```
.button {
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Если я с ответом попал не по адресу прошу строго не судить.

Answer (score 0):

Первое можно сделать с помощью css position:absolute.

Второе - с помощью javascript и управления видимостью элементов html (это уже обсуждалось здесь).